# Unrecognized selector sent to instance in storyboard

Tags: swift, storyboard, nsview

I am trying to make my own view superclass. This project is completely new, with only some changes I'll write. I created an experimental framework called `OrionGraphics` and I include it in `ViewController.swift`, which I completely deleted. Then I create the view class with inheritance from `OGView`.

I have literally zero idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm relatively good in SwiftUI, but obviously I'm really new to Storyboards.

I have linked the classes correctly. I set the View's Class to `OGView` and module to `OrionGraphics` and ViewController's Class to `ViewController` with inherited module.

**OrionApp**

*ViewController.swift*

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  OrionApp
//
//  Created by Fildom on 27.10.2022.
//

import OrionGraphics

class ViewController: OGView {
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        print("loaded")
    }
}
```

**OrionGraphics**

*OGView.swift*

```
//
//  OGView.swift
//  OrionGraphics
//
//  Created by Fildom on 27.10.2022.
//

import MetalKit

open class OGView: MTKView {
    public var preferredColorPixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
    public var renderer: OGRenderer
    
    public required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
            fatalError("[OrionGraphics] - FATAL: Could not create a system default device. Does your device support MetalKit?")
        }
        
        renderer = OGRenderer(device: device)
        
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        self.colorPixelFormat = preferredColorPixelFormat
        self.delegate = renderer
        self.device = device
        
        setClearColor(r: 0.4, g: 0.9, b: 0.3, a: 1.0)
    }
    
    public func setClearColor(r: Double, g: Double, b: Double, a: Double) {
        self.clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(r, g, b, a)
    }
}
```

*OGRenderer.swift*

```
//
//  OGRenderer.swift
//  OrionGraphics
//
//  Created by Fildom on 27.10.2022.
//

import MetalKit

open class OGRenderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {
    public var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
    public var renderPipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    public var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer!
    public var vertices: [OGVertex] = [
        OGVertex(position: SIMD3<Float>(0,1,0), color: SIMD4<Float>(1,0,0,1)),
        OGVertex(position: SIMD3<Float>(-1,-1,0), color: SIMD4<Float>(0,1,0,1)),
        OGVertex(position: SIMD3<Float>(1,-1,0), color: SIMD4<Float>(0,0,1,1))
    ]
    
    public init(device: MTLDevice) {
        super.init()
        createCommandQueue(device: device)
        createPipelineState(device: device)
        createBuffers(device: device)
    }
    
    public func createCommandQueue(device: MTLDevice) {
        commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()
    }
    
    public func createPipelineState(device: MTLDevice) {
        let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary()
        
        print(library == nil ? "NO DEFAULT LIBRARY = NIL" : "YES. DEFAULT LIBRARY EXISTS")
        
        let vertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "baseVertex")
        let fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "baseFragment")
        
        print("updated")
        
        let renderPipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        
        renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        
        renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
        renderPipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
        
        do {
            renderPipelineState = try device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: renderPipelineDescriptor)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    public func createBuffers(device: MTLDevice) {
        vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices, length: MemoryLayout<OGVertex>.stride * vertices.count, options: [])
    }
    
    public func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) { }
    
    public func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable,
         let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else {return}
         
         let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
         let commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
         commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState)
         
         commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
        
         commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertices.count)
         commandEncoder?.endEncoding()
         commandBuffer?.present(drawable)
         commandBuffer?.commit()
    }
}
```

*Shaders.metal*

```
//
//  Shaders.metal
//  OrionGraphics
//
//  Created by Fildom on 27.10.2022.
//

#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct VertexIn {
    float3 position;
    float4 color;
};

struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[ position ]];
    float4 color;
};

vertex VertexOut baseVertex(const device VertexIn *vertices [[ buffer(0) ]],
uint vertexID [[ vertex_id ]]) {
    VertexOut vOut;
    vOut.position = float4(vertices[vertexID].position,1);
    vOut.color = vertices[vertexID].color;
    return vOut;
}

fragment float4 baseFragment(VertexOut vIn [[ stage_in ]]) {
    return vIn.color;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
2022-10-27 18:54:05.851069+0200 OrionApp[5893:191390] [Nib Loading] Failed to connect (storyboard) outlet from (OrionApp.ViewController) to (NSStoryboard): missing setter or instance variable
2022-10-27 18:54:05.851705+0200 OrionApp[5893:191390] -[OrionApp.ViewController _setIsContentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa98c020a00
2022-10-27 18:54:05.858096+0200 OrionApp[5893:191390] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): -[OrionApp.ViewController _setIsContentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa98c020a00
```

Comment: Pretty sure this has nothing to do with metal and it is just a misconfigured storyboard

Comment: `ViewController` must be a subclass of `NSViewController`.